# AngularJS: How to access a dynamically generated element within a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say you have:

```
pre: function preLink(scope, element, attrs) {
  element.append('<div id="foo">foo</div>');
}
```

... and then you want to get a handle on the new foo element.

How is that possible?

Currently I have to run $compile on it, assign a directive to the div, and access it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this you mean?

```
var demo = angular.element('<div id="foo">foo</div>');
demo.bind('click', scope.clickingCallback);
element.append(demo);
```

Comment: Exactly.  Create the element, then add it.  Thanks.